# Ruby: DB Query to return the model with the highest sum total of a DB column between two dates

Tags: ruby, postgresql

I have two models.. a `Shop` model and an `Order` model.

I'm running postgres and Ruby.

The relationships are as follows:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :shop

class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
```

The `Orders` table has a column called `order_amount`

In english what I would like is the top 5 shops and their summed `order_amount` with the highest summed `order_amount` in the month of November 2023.

This is just getting me the summed order total for November, and not the top shops..

```
 Order.where(created_at: Date.parse("2022-11-01").beginning_of_day..Date.parse("2022-11-30").end_of_day).sum(:order_amount)
```

What I'm hoping to return is a list like this:

```
#1 Shop X - $50,000
#2 Shop Y - $48,000
#3 Shop Z - $45,000
```

What do you all think?

Comment: Add a `group` clause e.g. `group(:id)` or `group(:name)`